# Tengo un problema mostrando elementos de una base de datos remota con RecyclerView y CardView en AndroidStudio

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, recyclerview, cardview

estoy haciendo un proyecto en donde quiero hacer una tienda de mangas con base de datos remota utilizando 000webhost y el phpMyadmin que proporciona. El problema surge debido a que quiero usar un recyclerview con un cardview que muestre los mangas que tengo, el problema, es que no me muestra absolutamente nada, ni siquiera la imagen por defecto que tiene el cardview. Les muestro mi codigo y el archivo PHP que estoy usando.

Codigo de getter and setter:

```
package com.example.mangastorews;

public class manga_modelo {
    private String idmanga, titulo, autor, editorial, clasificacion, precio, portada;

    public manga_modelo() { }

    public manga_modelo(String idmanga ,String titulo, String autor, String editorial, String clasificacion, String precio, String portada) {
        this.idmanga = idmanga;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.editorial = editorial;
        this.clasificacion = clasificacion;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.portada = portada;
    }

    public String getIdmanga() { return idmanga; }

    public void setIdmanga(String idmanga) { this.idmanga = idmanga; }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) { this.titulo = titulo; }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) { this.autor = autor; }

    public String getEditorial() { return editorial; }

    public void setEditorial(String editorial) { this.editorial = editorial; }

    public String getClasificacion() {
        return clasificacion;
    }

    public void setClasificacion(String clasificacion) { this.clasificacion = clasificacion; }

    public String getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(String precio) { this.precio = precio; }

    public String getPortada() { return portada; }

    public void setPortada(String portada) { this.portada = portada; }
}
```

Código Adaptador:

```
package com.example.mangastorews;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class mangaAdaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter<mangaAdaptador.mangaviewHolder> {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<manga_modelo>mangasList;

    public mangaAdaptador(Context ctx, List<manga_modelo> mangasList){
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        this.mangasList = mangasList;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public mangaviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_manga, parent, false);
        return new mangaviewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull mangaAdaptador.mangaviewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.titulo.setText(mangasList.get(position).getTitulo());
        holder.autor.setText(mangasList.get(position).getAutor());
        holder.editorial.setText(mangasList.get(position).getEditorial());
        holder.clasficacion.setText(mangasList.get(position).getClasificacion());
        holder.precio.setText(mangasList.get(position).getPrecio());

        Picasso.get().load(mangasList.get(position).getPortada()).into(holder.portada);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mangasList.size();
    }

    public class mangaviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView titulo, autor, editorial, clasficacion, precio;
        ImageView portada;

        public mangaviewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
            autor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAutor);
            editorial = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEditorial);
            clasficacion= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvClasificacion);
            precio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrecio);

            portada = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgManga);
        }
    }
}
```

Codigo de la actividad principal:

```
package com.example.mangastorews;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtEmail, edtContra;
    Button btnLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edtEmail=findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        edtContra=findViewById(R.id.edtContra);
        btnLogin=findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                validarUsuario("https://mangastoremx.000webhostapp.com/validar_usuario.php");
            }
        });
    }

    private void validarUsuario(String URL){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                  if (!response.isEmpty()){
                      Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PrincipalActivity.class);
                      startActivity(intent);
                  }else {
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Usuario o contraseña incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parametros.put("userEmail",edtEmail.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("userPass",edtContra.getText().toString());
                return parametros;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

Archivo PHP:

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";

   $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM manga");
   while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))
   {
    echo $consulta['idmanga'];
    echo $consulta['titulo'];
    echo $consulta['autor'];
    echo $consulta['editorial'];
    echo $consulta['clasficacion'];
    echo $consulta['precio'];
    echo $consulta['portada'];
    
   }
   

include "cerrarconexion.php";
?>
```

También debo aclarar que el recyclerview no es mi primera pantalla ya que tengo una pantalla de login que si me funciona perfectamente, tengo las librerias de recyclervieww, cardview y volley y como dije anteriormente, el login con internet si funciono. De verdad les agradecería muchísimo que me proporcionaran una forma de arreglar esto, ya que tengo muchos días atorado y no se como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el fallo. Si vez esto y tienes el mismo problema que yo muy probablemente estés tratando de mostrar un solo elemento en el recycler, esto hace que no se muestre hasta que des clic en el recyclerview. Trata de agregar mas elementos a tu base de datos y con eso funcionara el recycler de forma perfecta